# How to create a new remote branch with EGit?

Tags: branch, egit, git-remote

Let's say I have an Eclipse Project which uses versioning control with EGit and is connected with a remote repository `git@myrepo.com:git2013`. In my project, under the local branch `newstuff`, I create and change some files. Now, I want to push this to a remote branch named `newstuff` in my remote repository. But my remote repository only holds a branch `master`.

How do I create a new remote branch called `newstuff`?

**PS: Please do not answer with command-line git commands; describe how to do it in EGit.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the section "[Configuring upstream push](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Configuring_upstream_push) " in order to push a given branch:

[image: Configure push in Egit]

Pushing a branch which doesn't exist yet on a remote repo will create it on said remote.

You can specify the [refspec](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Refspecs) you want to use, or use [Push ref specification](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Ref_Specifications).

[image: Push refspec]

That above would push all local branches.

---

Update [December 2013 (Egit 3.2)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/3.2): as mentioned in [robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21457729/6309) (upvoted), you now have:

> Push Branch / Initial Push wizard simplifies pushing a branch and also allows upstream configuration for new branches created by the push operation.
>   Improve UI of upstream configuration when creating a branch:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/6/6f/Egit-3.2-PushBranchWizard.png]

Answer (score 10):

In EGit 3.2, there is now a dedicated wizard for this use case:

1. Select *Team* → *Push Branch...* in the context menu
2. In the wizard, you can change which remote you want to push to and whether pulling on this branch should merge or rebase:

   [image: Push Branch in EGit]
3. The next page will show a confirmation before doing the push, you can then finish the wizard.

After that, you can simply use *Push to Upstream* when the branch is checked out to push to the remote branch, or *Pull* to get the changes from the remote branch.